# Shapefile layer export issue

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, export

I am using QGIS to define polygons in a shapefile layer which I am then exporting as an ESRI shapefile for use with JMP.

The polygon layer looks correct on-screen in QGIS, but the exported files have multiple problems:

- polygon names have not stayed with the associated polygons - the names are still present, just labeling a different polygon in the output files.
- entire polygons are 'missing' in the output files.

Is there a way to fix this problem?

---

I have narrowed this issue down to just the 'dropped' polygons portion of the problem.

The other 2 issues I cited originally have been resolved as follows:
-The 'old' polygon boundaries were being drawn by JMP from an out-of-date map in the system.
-The map label scrambling was due to not adding a sequentially numbered column to the .dbf file.  The 'id' column appearing in the dbf file does not match the 'id' column of the .shp file, however, the 1st row of the .dbf file does correspond to polygon with id = 1 in the .shp file.